# Чому „дошки”, але „дощок”? Яким правилом керується це чергування?

Tags: фонетика, правопис, чергування

Читав „2084” Буалема Сансаля і наштовхнувся на таке:

> ... додає один лист бляхи до другого, дошки до дощок, замащує шпари глиною з соломою...

Те, що це слово зʼявилося водночас і в називному, і в родовому відмінку, дало мені змогу побачити відмінність і щось на кшталт чергування **ш** і **щ**.

Як на мене, звучить *дощок* справді краще за *дошок*, але як називається правило, за яким одну літеру замінюють на іншу?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Називає ся [*чергування звуків*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2), відки й витікає [*cпрощення груп приголосних*](//uk.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%83_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85), а саме **шчк–шк**, яке, як видно, не завше спрацьовує. З тамтешніх прикладів:

| відмінок | однина | множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| називний | [горщок](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%BA) | горшки |
| родовий | горшка | горшків |
| давальний | горшку, горшкові | горшкам |
| знахідний | **горщок** | **горшки** |
| орудний | горшком | горшками |
| місцевий | горшку | горшках |
| кличний | горшку | горшки |

| відмінок | однина | множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| називний | [зморшка](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0#97247) | зморшки |
| родовий | **зморшки** | **зморщок** |
| давальний | зморшці | зморшкам |
| знахідний | зморшку | зморшки |
| орудний | зморшкою | зморшками |
| місцевий | зморшці | зморшках |
| кличний | зморшко | зморшки |

Answer (score 0):

[**Правопис закінчень іменників І відміни**](https://webpen.com.ua/pages/Morphology_and_spelling/spelling_endings_nouns_I_case.html)

У родовому відмінку множини відбувається **словозміна**:

слово **вівця** має форму **овець**, **дошка** — **дощок**,
**зморшка** — **зморщок**, **гра** — **ігор**.

[image: Дошка родовий відмінок множини]